# Joomla 1.5 / Modification of YooTheme "ZOO" Component

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'll start out by mentioning that there **is** a developer forum for Zoo and I have used it already. My purpose posting here is that I typically get a thorough answer within minutes or hours at SO, whereas the responses on dev forums can be slow or non-existent due to the smaller population base.

My question regards Yootheme's ZOO 2.3.2. By default, a product "Frontpage" appears to have a "Categories" box rendered on top of the items. If one turns off all the available options in Frontpage/Template configuration (hide Titles, Count, Descriptions, etc.), an empty box still remains on top of the items.

I've been able to manually remove the box in its entirety by addressing the following file:

media/zoo/applications/product/templates/default/frontpage.php, and commenting out lines 84-92:

```
<!-- <?php

    // render categories
    if ($this->category->childrenHaveItems()) {
        $categoriestitle = $this->application->getParams()->get('content.categories_title');
        echo $this->partial('categories', compact('categoriestitle'));
    }

?> -->
```

Seems like there should be a more eloquent way of doing this on the admin backend, but I couldn't find one. Am I missing something or is my solution the best one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZOO is designed to easily be able to modify the built in templates to suit your needs. ZOO templates are meant to be overridden much like Joomla uses template overrides. Rather than editing the default template, you simply create a new template that does what you want it to. The default template should not be changed.

Here is the documentation on ZOO templates - http://www.yootheme.com/docs/home/item/create-a-new-template

Rather than edit the file you mention above, you make a new template here -

media/zoo/applications/product/templates/YOUR-TEMPLATE-NAME/frontpage.php

Then do all the changing you want without messing up the default.

Comment: Now there's an option I hadn't tried before! So it seems that the answer is "Yes, that's the best way to change the template", but "No, you shouldn't be modifying the source template." I'll have a look at those docs for creating new templates. Thank you for sharing that!

Comment: Exactly. Change all you want, just make a new template to do it. That also makes your work future proof as ZOO will never overwrite custom template file while it may overwrite the defaults if there is a change in them.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way:  First, you must identify what calls the item called "frontpage". In PURE yootheme at least it is called from "home" in the "mainmenu". So click "home" buton of the mainmenu, then over the right menu "Parameters(Basic)" you just chose "-select aplication-" instead "frontpage" and that's it.The Frontpage and its "box" are now gone. At least it works for me.